# How to create a face in between two already connected edges?

Tags: shortcut, topology, tools

[image]

Basically I'd like to create a new face right in that selected edge to achieve something like this:

[image]

Does Blender have a tool/option to do this or do I need to recreate all of that manually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can bevel the edges with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>:

[image: edge bevel]

Then you dissolve the vertices of these extra edges with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>:

[image: edge vertices dissolve]

Comment: Never thought of that honestly, many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To add to Hulifier's answer, you can also use the knife tool, <kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>A</kbd> to cut orthogonally, right click to release, <kbd>Enter</kbd> to validate, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> to dissolve the edges:

[image]